# Trying to find the probability of a sum of standard normal variables being greater than a set value in R

Tags: r, math, probability, probability-theory

I'm brand new to R, and I'm sure this should be an easy question for some people, but I can't figure it out.

How do I find the probability that an equation of independent standard normal variables is greater than a certain value using R?

Pr((x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) > 5)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random variable **x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2** follows the Chi-squared distribution with 3 degrees of freedom. So your probability is given in R by

```
pchisq(5, df = 3, lower.tail = FALSE)
```